# Int in argv[] breaks and just prints the int

Tags: c, argv

So I know this is basics but I have no clue where to find the right answers. the thing is I need to run a program with argument -s followed by a number telling it how many chars from input to skip, say we do (I run it in bash):

```
echo "hue" |./prog -s 2
```

which should then only print the `e` but instead the shell gives me

> 2someone@somewhere:

I am stuck for hours at this point not being able to figure it out, please, help.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char s;
    char input[8196];
    int i = 0;
    /* above initialized are variables needed for the root of the program to work */
    int s_num = 0; /* "-s" or skip */
    int cnt_1; /* lvl1 counter */
    /* Getting input */
    while ((s = getchar()) != EOF) {
        input[i] = s;
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;
    }

    /* If calling w/o arguments, the only thing that works */
    if (argc == 1) {
        //do stuff
    }

    /* Argument Check */  
    if (argc > 1) {
        printf("1\n");
        for (cnt_1 = 0; cnt_1 < argc; cnt_1++) {
            printf("2\n");

            if (strcmp(argv[cnt_1], "-s") == 1) {
                printf("3.1\n");
                int pom = cnt_1 + 1;
                int bqs = 0;
                for (int i = 0; argv[pom][i] != '\0'; ++i) {
                    bqs *= 10; bqs += argv[pom][i] - '0';
                }
                s_num = bqs;
            }
            ...
```

Comment: You say in the comments below "my bad I am forbidden from the use of <string.h>".  So just do a `char` by `char` comparison of the strings contained in the `argv` array of strings.  (It is not usually a good idea to write your own versions of functions already contained in C's standard library, unless it is a specifically assigned for you to do it that way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument, i.e. `argv[0]` contains the name of the executable.
So start your search for arguments at the second element of the array `argv[1]` and go from there.

```
for (cnt_1 = 1; cnt_1 < argc; cnt_1++)
//           ^  change 0 to 1 here
```

if, as you say in the comments, you are not allowed to use `<string.h>`, then perhaps you can perform a `char` by `char` comparison of each string contained in the array of strings of `argv[]` as you go through your loop:

```
...
if((argv[cnt_1][0] == '-') && (argv[cnt_1][1] == 's'))//argument "-s" found, handle it
{
    ...
```

Comment: now that is a good catch right there, but the thing is there is a printf() before the cycle begins and it does not go off so the program doesnt get that far

Comment: @JozefTománek - Use of getchar() (as opposed to starting with parsing `argv[]`) is very non-standard.  For one, `getchar()` will block unless input is provided, by design.    This link discusses _[more traditional methods to start a program by parsing `argv` and `argc`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv/)_ arguments.  Please take a look.  In any case, use one or the other method to handle command line arguments, not both.

Comment: solved with char by char comparison, props to @ryyker

Comment: @JozefTománek -  Thank you.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `char s;` should be `int s;` otherwise the loop `while ((s = getchar()) != EOF)` does not function correctly.  Depending on whether type `char` is signed or unsigned by default, it would stop prematurely on `\377` characters or fail to match `EOF` completely.
- you do not check if `i` is less than `sizeof(input)` before `input[i] = s;`.  Any sufficiently long input file will cause a buffer overrun.
- you should use `atoi(argv[cnt_1 + 1])` to convert the size argument, after checking if this argument is different from `NULL`.
- if you cannot use `strcmp()` to check argument values or `atoi()` to convert numbers, use pointer variables and check characters individually:

  ```
  char *p = argv[cnt_1];
  if (p[0] == '-' && p[1] == 's' && p[2] == '\0') {
      int skip = 0;
      char *s = argv[cnt_1 + 1];
      if (s != NULL) {
          while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') {
              skip = skip * 10 + *s++ - '0';
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- last but not least: if you can use `strcmp()`, you should not make assumptions about its return value beyond the fact that it can be negative, `0` or positive.  You should change `strcmp(argv[cnt_1], "-s") == 1` into `strcmp(argv[cnt_1], "-s") == 0` to check if the strings are identical. It `strcmp()` is your own implementation, it would be **very** error-prone to give it different semantics as you hint in the comments. Write instead an `strequal()` function that returns a boolean value and just test `if (strequal(argv[cnt_1], "-s"))`

Comment: atoi() is forbidden in this project

the 1st and 2nd point is correct thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @JozefTománek - Up-clicks are a good way of saying _thanks for pointing that out_.

Comment: @JozefTománek: read my updated answer: there was a silly bug indeed.

Comment: @ryyker: the OP cannot up-vote yet, it requires at least 15 rep... But you can, and so do I ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strcmp(argv[cnt_1], "-s") == 1)
```

That should be 0. `strcmp` returns 0 on equal.

> 0 1 2 3 1 2 2
>   3.1 2

That's what I get from the output and it's what could be expected as the last one is the value of the -s. Are you sure your strcmp works as it should?

Comment: my bad I am forbidden from the use of <string.h> so that is my own strcmp and returns 0 on eq

Comment: @JozefTománek are you sure your strcmp works as it should?

Comment: @JozefTománek: Don't reimplement standard functions with different semantics, it is evil.  Write a `strequal()` function that returns a boolean value and just test `if (strequal(argv[cnt_1], "-s")) {`